# Graphviz – horizontal edges between nodes

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

Good evening, I'm trying to generate graph using **graphviz**.

I can't figure out how to model **horizontal edges** between some nodes. I use the next code to generate this graph:

[image: Graph]

```
digraph{ rankdir=LR;
//{rank=same; "[0]"; "[10B1]"; "[62]"; "[8]"; "[9]"; "[10]";}
"[0]"->"[37]"; "[37]"->"[4]"; "[37]"->"[8]";
"[8]"->"[9]"; "[9]"->"[10]"; "[62]"->"[8]";
"[0]"->"[10B1]"; "[10B1]"->"[62]"; "[0]"->"[2]";
"[2]"->"[3]"; "[7]"->"[8]"; "[4]"->"[7]";
}
```

---

I would like to align the nodes [8], [10B1], [62] [8], [9] and [10] in **one horizontal line**.

Comment: Here you talk with people around the world somewhere is evening, somewhere is midnight and somewhere is morning :)

Comment: @SaeedAmiri Right :-). But nice day to everyone :-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to place those nodes in a [cluster](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery/directed/cluster.html). Inside that cluster, you can then set `rank=lr` to have the nodes placed left-to-right. It's important that you define the cluster and the nodes you want in it before you add the connecting edges to the rest of the graph.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly it :-).

Answer (score 7):

An other solution is to have the nodes which have to be aligned share the same value of the `group` attribute:

```
digraph{
rankdir=LR;

node[group=main];
"[0]"; "[10B1]"; "[62]"; "[8]"; "[9]";
node[group=""];

"[0]"->"[37]";
"[37]"->"[4]";
"[37]"->"[8]";
"[8]"->"[9]";
"[9]"->"[10]";
"[62]"->"[8]";
"[0]"->"[10B1]";
"[10B1]"->"[62]";
"[0]"->"[2]";
"[2]"->"[3]";
"[7]"->"[8]";
"[4]"->"[7]";
}
```

You could achieve something similar by adjusting `weight` or using `constraint=false` for some edges.

Here's [an other example using group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671238/forcing-main-line-nodes-into-a-straight-line-in-graphviz-or-alternatives/4673624#4673624), and an [other example using weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671238/forcing-main-line-nodes-into-a-straight-line-in-graphviz-or-alternatives/4671684#4671684) (same question).

Comment: Bad graph with this data (http://pastebin.com/1YeaJPtt). It is posible to fix it?

Comment: Yep: http://pastebin.com/NjTN6wC7 - changed the order of the nodes a bit, and added `constraint=false` for one edge