# Center last node of a graph

Tags: graphviz, dot

```
digraph {
  1 -> 2 -> 3;
  2 -> { rank = sink; end};
}
```

[image: example]

How can I force the "end" node to be centered horizontally (in the same column as the first node)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `group` attribute of the nodes:

```
digraph {
  3[group=b];
  node[group=a]
  1 -> 2 -> end;
  2 -> 3;
}
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4673624/63733) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4671684/63733) answer.