# Edge pointing at edge with Graphviz and Dot

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

I would like to point an edge towards another edge in `graphviz` using the `dot` format.

What I got so far:

```
digraph G {
    Hello->dummy;
    dummy->World;
    dummy[shape=point width=0];
    Test->dummy;
}
```

which produces

[image: current status]

what I would like to get is something more similar to this:

[image]

Any ideas how to do so?

Comment: [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671238/forcing-main-line-nodes-into-a-straight-line-in-graphviz-or-alternatives) details a few tricks to force a straight line.  But it appears that the nodes which you want to be in a line have to be in the same group (i.e. have to all have the same properties).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe `rank = same` does the trick?

```
digraph G
{
  { rank = same; Test; dummy }        // dummy and Test on the same level
  dummy[ shape = point, width = 0 ];                         // connector
  Hello -> dummy[ arrowhead = none ];    // remove arrowhead to connector
  dummy -> Test[ dir = back ];         // you want Test on the right side
  dummy -> World;
}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Hmm, this will only work for a small example like the one above. My problem is, that I would like to plot "Extended Argumentation Frameworks" where you have a lot of contradictory attacks and attacks on attacks. A typical network could look like the following screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qphs9uk1fxk88cn/Screenshot%202016-07-18%2017.26.43.png?dl=0 As you can see, this would be rather difficult to represent with the above approach. I know it from tikzpicture in latex that you can simply draw edges and define that there is an anchor point in the center of the edge. That would be awesome!

Comment: i had to put `width=0.0001` in connector line to make it work

Answer (score 0):

`[arrowhead=none]` with you `dummy` middleman does the job for me.

```
digraph G {
    Hello->dummy[arrowhead=none];
    dummy->World;
    dummy[shape=point width=0];
    Test->dummy;
}
```

[image: result graph]

I've added [feature request](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/issues/1656) for it in Graphviz's issue tracker.